# Adding Health Check to .NET Isolated Azure Function

Tags: .net, azure-functions, .net-5, health-check, azure-http-trigger

I could not find any resources to add health checks to a HTTPTrigger function app, running in .NET 5.0 Isolated.

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
        {
            configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices((builder, services) =>
        {
            var configuration = builder.Configuration;
            services.AddDbContext(configuration);
                    
            // Add healthcheck here
            services.AddHealthChecks()
            // ...
            // Map health checks
                    
        })
        .Build();

    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

This [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-6.0) states I can add MapHealthChecks (but in asp.net core)

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapHealthChecks("/healthz");

app.Run();
```

How do I translate this to run in my dotnet-isolated application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
app.MapHealthChecks("/healthz");
```

The line above under the hood creates ASP CORE [middleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/HealthChecks/src/HealthCheckMiddleware.cs) and injects `IHealthCheckService` to call `CheckHealthAsync()` and return HTTP response. In the Azure Function you can:

- Inject `IHealthCheckService` to constructor, call `CheckHealthAsync()` and return response.

  ```
    private readonly IHealthCheckService _healthCheck;

    public DependencyInjectionFunction(IHealthCheckService healthCheck)
    {
        _healthCheck = healthCheck;
    }

    [Function(nameof(DependencyInjectionFunction))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req,
        FunctionContext context)
    {
         var healthStatus = await _healthCheck.CheckHealthAsync();
         #format health status and return HttpResponseData
    }
  ```
- Implement your own azure function [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#middleware), check for path '/healthz then resolve `IHealthCheckService` and return health status immediately