# How to configure Health Check for Azure Function App

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I didn't come across any source with the correct answer(I have tried 2 approaches but none of them seem to work), hence posting my question here.

I am using a time trigger Azure Function to check health of other endpoints(which would be read from configuration). For that I'm using the package - `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks`.

**# Approach 1**

`Startup.cs` class:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(HealthChecker.Startup))]
namespace HealthChecker
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // Getting the IConfiguration instance
            var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;

            // Registering health checks
            builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();

            // Calling the method that defines health checks
            HealthCheckDefinitions.ConfigureHealthChecks(builder.Services.AddHealthChecks(), configuration);
        }
    }


  }
```

`HealthCheckDefinitions.cs` class:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using System;

namespace HealthChecker
{
public static class HealthCheckDefinitions
{

    public static void ConfigureHealthChecks(IHealthChecksBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        try
        {
            builder.AddCheck("test", () =>
            {
                    bool isHealthy = false;
                    // Perform a test to check the connectivity to an endpoint
                    // .....

                    if (isHealthy)
                      return HealthCheckResult.Healthy("API connection is healthy.");
                    else
                      return HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("API connection is unhealthy.");
            });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The issue here is the control never steps into`builder.AddCheck()` although the `ConfigureHealthChecks` method gets called.

**# Approach 2**

I followed the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and tried like this:

`Startup.cs` class:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(HealthChecker.Startup))]
namespace HealthChecker
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // Get the IConfiguration instance
            var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;

            // Register health checks
            builder.Services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck<SampleHealthCheck>("SampleHealthCheckName"); ;
        }
    }
}
```

`SampleHealthCheck.cs` class:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HealthChecker
{
    public class SampleHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
    {
        public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(
            HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var isHealthy = true;

            // ...

            if (isHealthy)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(
                    HealthCheckResult.Healthy("A healthy result."));
            }

            return Task.FromResult(
                new HealthCheckResult(
                    context.Registration.FailureStatus, "An unhealthy result."));
        }
    }
}
```

The same issue persists here also. The control never steps into `CheckHealthAsync()` of `SampleHealthCheck.cs` class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I usually don't use Health Checks for Azure Functions based APIs, and the reason is because most of the time I use the consumption plan, and the function won't  be running all the time. My way to monitor it is through Application Insights.

Comment: Hey, the requirement in my case is to monitor the health every 5 mins, hence going with this approach. :)

Comment: You've setup the healthcheck in DI, but you haven't created a function that uses it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75919014/configuring-net-6-azure-function-app-healthchecks/75920076

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75919014/configuring-net-6-azure-function-app-healthchecks/75920076 yes, indeed, I was testing without creating a function that was using the dependency. Thank you so much!